# AngularJS: Checking the value of the radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have been using AngularJS for a while now. I have my a radio button which gives users the option and json data that has the value of the correct answers. How do I make the comparison?

Code:

```
var testControllers = angular.module('testControllers', []);

testControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data;
    $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
  });
}]);

testControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams' ,function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
    if($routeParams.itemId > 0){
        $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) - 1;
    }
    else{
        $scope.prevItem = $scope.questions.length - 1;
    }


    if($routeParams.itemId < $scope.questions.length-1){
        $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) + 1;
    }
    else{
        $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }
  });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
<section class="artistinfo">
    <div class="mcq" ng-model: "questions">
      <center><a href = "#details/{{prevItem}}" class = "button">PREV</a>
      <a href = "#details/{{nextItem}}" class = "button">NEXT</a></center>
      <div class = "qanda">
        <h3 class = "qnum">QUESTION {{parseInt(whichItem)+1}}</h3>
        <p class = "ques" math-jax-bind = "questions[whichItem].ques"></p>    
        <ul>
              <li class= "optlist" ng-repeat="item in questions[whichItem].opts">
              <label class="formgroup">
              <input type="radio" name = "q" ng-model = "$parent.selopt" value = "{{item.pos}}"><span math-jax-bind = "item.val"></span>
             </label>
             </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <center><a href = "#list" class = "button">List View</a></center>
      <p>{{selopt}}</p>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Here is the JSON data that I have:

```
"opts":[  
    {  
      "pos":"A",
      "val":"3"
    },
    {  
      "pos":"B",
      "val":"6"
    },
    {  
      "pos":"C",
      "val":"9"
    },
    {  
      "pos":"D",
      "val":"0"
    }
    "answer":"B"
]
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Comment: I'm guessing that $scope.questions becomes the array "opts" , correct?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I need to compare the selected option with the answer

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$parent.selopt` contains the selected value (parent scope's `selopt`).

If you need an explanation: when you select a value, by clicking the radio button, the variable that you specify in the `ng-model` attribute of your directive

```
<input type="radio" name = "q" ng-model = "$parent.selopt" value = "{{item.pos}}">
```

will be updated, with the selected value.

If you want to compare that with `opts.answer`, you can simply do:

```
 $scope.questions.answer == $parent.selopt
```

Mind you, that your JSON, is invalid.

It should be:

```
[{
    "pos": "A",
    "val": "3"
}, {
    "pos": "B",
    "val": "6"
}, {
    "pos": "C",
    "val": "9"
}, {
    "pos": "D",
    "val": "0"
}, {
    "answer": "B"
}]
```

You can always use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate it.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, thank you. But how do I comapre the selopt with the `answer` from my JSON file?

Comment: Not me, you :P Given that you got the array `opts`, from the `$http.get`, and saved the result (`data`) in `$scope.questions`

Comment: Where do I make the comparison: ` $scope.questions.answer == $parent.selopt`? Within HTML?

Comment: No, in your controller.